# How to take a system screenshot of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to take a system screenshot like from the buttons on the phone? For example, I clicked a button in which the

```
Future.delayed( const Duration(seconds: 5), () => _doTakeScreenshot());
```

I pressed the HOME button to go to the desktop, 5 seconds passed and a screenshot was taken. I want to take a screenshot OUTSIDE the app.
I found the package [screenshot:^1.2.3](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot). But he cannot take a screenshot outside of the application

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) for taking screenshots, `screenshotController.capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))`

Comment: I pointed it out in the question ... I need to take a screenshot outside of the application. On the desktop or in another application ...

Comment: As far as I know you won't find any packages that would help you take screenshots outside of the app since this is considered suspicious activity and goes against the security guidelines, in other words what happens outside of your app is none of your business and taking screenshots is considered spying

Comment: But is there a way to do this? I need this for internal use.